# ¿Cómo puedo validar un formulario con varios radio buttons?

Tags: html, jsp, radiobutton

Mi problema es que tengo una lista con 40 preguntas de las cuales en cada pregunta hay 2 `radio-buttons` con diferente `id`, mismo `name`, llamar por el `name` pregunta por pregunta es tedioso y quisiera saber, si hay otro modo quizás ¿llamarle por la clase tal vez?

```html
<table  id="table"  width="100%"  align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="subtitulo">LISTA DE VERIFICACION </td>
<td class="Subtitulo">SI</td>
 <td class="Subtitulo">NO</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NA.</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">ACTIVIDAD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba1</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio1"  name="a" class="giru"></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio2" name="a" class="giru" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba 2</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio3" name="b" class="giru"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio4" name="b" class="giru"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Prueba 3</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1"  id="miradio5"  name="e" class="giru"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2"  id="miradio6"  name="e" class="giru"/></td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Usas Jquery? seria rapido

Comment: Cual es tu error?

Comment: como  llamaría por Jquery? por el tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Para esto no necesitas realmente JavaScript o jQuery, puedes usar HTML dándole el atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#attr-required) a los radio buttons. Al ponerle `required`, el navegador no dejará enviar el formulario hasta que alguno de los radio buttons con el mismo nombre haya sido seleccionado.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando con tu código. Intenta enviar el formulario sin seleccionar respuesta en alguna de las preguntas, el navegador bloqueará el envío porque no se seleccionó un campo requerido:

```html
<form>
<table  id="table"  width="100%"  align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="subtitulo">LISTA DE VERIFICACION </td>
<td class="Subtitulo">SI</td>
 <td class="Subtitulo">NO</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NA.</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">ACTIVIDAD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba1</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio1"  name="a" class="giru" required></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio2" name="a" class="giru" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba 2</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio3" name="b" class="giru" required/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio4" name="b" class="giru" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Prueba 3</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1"  id="miradio5"  name="e" class="giru" required/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2"  id="miradio6"  name="e" class="giru" required/></td>
</tr> 
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega Jquery en `<head`:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Validando:

```
if($("[name='a']:checked").val()!=undefined){
    alert('seleccionado:' + $("[name='a']:checked").val());
}else{
    alert('sin seleccinar');
}
```

Podrias hacerlo una funcion:

```
ValidaCheck : function(vname){
    if($("[name='"+vname+"']:checked").val()!=undefined){
        alert('seleccionado:' + $("[name='a']:checked").val());
    }else{
        alert('sin seleccinar');
    }
}

//invocando
validaCheck('a');
validaCheck('b');
validaCheck('e');
```

Comment: ¿y haría eso para cada una de las preguntas?

Comment: podrías hacerlo una función, luego un array con los `names` que podría ayudarte a personalizar el mensaje de validación, *Falta llenar el dato a*, etc.

Comment: Si te ha servido dale +1 y márcala cómo válida, si no contácteme por los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente ejemplo te agrego en JavaScript una función que te genera una matriz con el valor seleccionado por el usuario únicamente obteniendo los elementos por su clase.

```js
function validarForm () {
  var lstRadios = document.getElementsByClassName("giru");
  var respuestas = [];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(lstRadios, function(elemento) {
    var pregunta = [ false, false ];
    if (elemento.checked) {
      pregunta[elemento.value - 1] = true;
      respuestas.push(pregunta);
    }
  });

  console.log(respuestas);
}
```

```html
<table  id="table"  width="100%"  align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="subtitulo">LISTA DE VERIFICACION </td>
<td class="Subtitulo">SI</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NO</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NA.</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">ACTIVIDAD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba1</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio1"  name="a" class="giru"></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio2" name="a" class="giru" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label >Prueba 2</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio3" name="b" class="giru"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio4" name="b" class="giru"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Prueba 3</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1"  id="miradio5"  name="e" class="giru"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2"  id="miradio6"  name="e" class="giru"/></td>
</tr> 
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="validarForm();">Validar</button>
```